# How to update an existing custom label and its translations in apex?

Tags: api, salesforce, metadata, apex

By using [apex-mdapi](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) we can create new custom labels with translations, but I was unable to read them back using readMetadata method. Will it be possible to read and update an existing custom label and its translation using MetadataService?